# Replicate one database in one server to 2 other servers SQL2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, standard-edition

In product
ion, we  have a transactional replication between 2 servers with data from one database  going from server A to Server B. We now want to add another server C for the short period of time and get replication working from Server A to Server C.
So in short,  one database from **server A** replicated one way  to **Server B** and **Server C** simultaneously. Is that possible in SQL2008 standard edition ? And if yes then which type of replication would work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible, and most types of Replication should allow you to accomplish this, but since you said you only need it to synchronize in one direction then [Transactional Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/transactional-replication?view=sql-server-ver15) is probably the most ideal solution. It's also typically the most flexible type of Replication, especially since it supports heterogenous Publishers:

> Transactional replication is typically used in server-to-server environments and is appropriate in each of the following cases:

> You want incremental changes to be propagated to Subscribers as they occur.

> The application requires low latency between the time changes are made at the Publisher and the changes arrive at the Subscriber.

> The application requires access to intermediate data states. For example, if a row changes five times, transactional replication allows an application to respond to each change (such as firing a trigger), not simply the net data change to the row.

> The Publisher has a very high volume of insert, update, and delete activity.

> The Publisher or Subscriber is a non-SQL Server database, such as Oracle.

> By default, Subscribers to transactional publications should be treated as read-only, because changes are not propagated back to the Publisher. However, transactional replication does offer options that allow updates at the Subscriber.

Since your database on `ServerA` is already setup as a Publisher, you likely only need to follow the second set of steps of setting up a new subscription per [**Create a subscription to the transactional publication**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/tutorial-replicating-data-between-continuously-connected-servers?view=sql-server-ver15#create-a-subscription-to-the-transactional-publication).

Note that any tables replicated via Transactional Replication require primary keys defined on them, and any indexed views require a unique clustered index.

Answer (score -2):

I was using **Server B** as its own distributor, and it was a pull subscription hence the above method did not work. I then deleted the existing replication and set it up as per link suggested by J.D.( push replication) and it worked like a dream.

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" in the answer box.  See [what to do when someone answers my question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).